# Corrupted installation

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-install-apk

I've been having an issue with few devices with my app. For some reason, some users keep getting the error code 910 when they try to install the app. But I can not figure out why. Also, these users can not directly install the .apk either.

What I tried was let them:
try signed version with V1&V2,
try signed version with V1&V2 with no obfuscation to see if it was the issue.

None of this helped.

What users tried:
Uninstall the app
Clear Google Play Cache
Restart phone
Install again.

Does anyone know what this issue is about ?

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose without more information. Error code 910 just means the app wasn't installed after the install process finished, which you knew already (source, I walk on Google Play). It sounds like you've got good communication with the users. If it happens again I'd recommend getting the logs from them (using a bug report). PackageManager logs might have more info. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report

Comment: Well since they can not install, I can not get any logs. But will try your comment. How to get PackageManager to give out logs ? Since I can not replicate this behaviour on my phones